# How to grab output of terminal when issuing commands to use in a program?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtcore, avrdude

I am writing an `avrdude` helper program that facilitates calling a few command-line arguments. When issuing avrdude commands in the console a series of output results will be displayed on the screen. Is there anyway to grab that output and display it in a GUI window (using Qt, if that matters)?

I figured I could take the output and redirect it to a file (`avrdude -args > textFile.txt`) that could be read and displayed on the screen at runtime if nothing else.

Just wondering if there are any other alternatives to capturing this output.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key classes are [QProcess](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html) and [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) or some similar GUI widget here as follows:

```
QProcess avrDudeProcess;
avrDudeProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
avrDudeProcess.start("avrdude", optionList);
if (!avrDudeProcess.waitForStarted())
    return false;

if (!avrDudeProcess.waitForFinished())
    return false;

QByteArray output = avrDudeProcess.readAll();
myLabel.setText(output);
```

Comment: Very nice. `.. explicitly read all data from either of the two channels [stderr, stdout] by calling readAllStandardOutput() or readAllStandardError().`

Comment: @sherrellbc: or setProcessChannelMode if you need both as per my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, that is what you are looking for.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

That is an exmaple:

```
/* First open the command for reading. */
FILE * file = popen("/bin/ls /etc/", "r");

char output[100];
/* Read the output line by line */
while (fgets(output, 100, file) != NULL) 
{
    printf("%s", output); /* show the result */
}

/* close */
pclose(file);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think you missed the fact that the OP was looking for a QT solution. `"... and display it in a GUI window (using Qt, if that matters)?"`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: was it you downvoting my answer? Interestingly enough, both answers got a -1 simultaneously and mine did not get any explanation.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It wasn't me who down-voted anyone (I actually +1'd yours). This one does miss the whole QT thing, which is why I commented, but didn't downvote. I will usually comment with "-1" on down-voted answers.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: you are a fair contributor in my eyes then. That makes me happy. I get lots of unexplained downvotes (99%) and that does not help improving the posts. Perhaps the C tag misled Thalles. I think the OP could omit that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Agreed. I removed the C tag.

Comment: Yes that is right, I was thinking in C. But I am glad you've found the answer you were looking for.@JonathonReinhart